# Getting error in compiling make file for plugin build in qgis 1.8

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I am using QGIS 1.8 for building plugin. For developing i am using following ref this link [example](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html). where in this step 6 where compile the makefile in OSGeo4W. gives error pyuic4:command not found. I am also showing print screen of error:[image]. Please help me to over come this error Or running same in python console of qgis 1.8

Answer (score 1):

`pyuic4` is part of PyQt4, which is part of OSGeo4W. In case its installer gives you a choice of what components to install, make sure you also picked pyqt4, which is short for "pythong bindings for qt4". Did QGIS not complain about python when you were using it (eg. the plugin manager)?

So, if you do have PyQt4 already, you may just need to set the search path, so `pyuic4` can be found. Or in the unlikely case that the bundled version is missing this generator, install a full version from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download.

Comment: pyqt4 gets installed when you install qgis.  This seems to be a bug with the make file on windows not liking pyuic4.bat.  I have run into it before.

Comment: yes pyqt4 has been already installed with Qgis 1.8.

Comment: I have also checked the path for pyuic4.bat file which i found correct.

Comment: The errors suggest some quoting problems, so I'd try installing to a path without any spaces in its name. You could also look at the makefile that gives the error, maybe it's simple to fix (your log is too short to tell where it went wrong though).

Comment: I tired all ways to rum make file. But didn't get any solution finally i have run command in make file one by one in OSGEO4W command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran in the same problem with the current QGIS 2.6.1 by just typing make I had the same error. I've searched for the pyuic4.bat file and it was located correctly. SO I just used the absolute path in the OSGEO4W Shell:

```
C:\Users\ricckli\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis2leaf>make
pyuic4 -o ui_qgis2leaf.py ui_qgis2leaf.ui
make: pyuic4: Command not found
make: *** [ui_qgis2leaf.py] Error 127
```

This one was working without a problem:

```
C:\Users\ricckli\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis2leaf>C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\pyuic4 -o ui_q
gis2leaf.py ui_qgis2leaf.ui
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of Plugin Builder, you only need to compile resources.qrc because the .ui is now loaded dynamically.
I am using QGIS 2.6.1 and in this version there is no need to compile uic file.